# Getting a CORS err and GCP functions err "Function invocation was interrupted. Error: memory limit exceeded" while trying to scrape a site using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions, puppeteer

Im using React and I'm attempting to scrape a site from my frontend utilizing a Firebase cloud function and Puppeteer. Oddly enough I get the code working on my local server, but when attempting to implement the same code on my live server via firebase, I'm getting this CORS error below.

[image: CORS err]

Below is the code on my frontend, where I make the request:

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import {Typography, Container, TextField, Button} from "@material-ui/core";
import axios from 'axios'


export const Scraper = ({ formData, setForm, navigation }) => {
  const { firstName, lastName, displayName, services} = formData;
  const [url, setUrl] = useState('')
  const [html, setHtml] = useState('')

  const handleScrape = async() => {

    try {
      const response = await axios.get('https://us-central1-cuti-app-7c963.cloudfunctions.net/app/scrape', {
        params:  {url: url}
      })
      if(response){
          console.log(response.data)
      }else{
        console.log("Failure Link retrieval")
      }      
  } catch (error) {
      console.log("This is the Error:", error)
  }



  return (
    <Container maxWidth="xs" style={{marginTop:'20px', textAlign: "center"}}>
      <Typography variant='h4'>Prospect URLL</Typography>
  
      
      <TextField
        label="Booksy"
        name="url"
        value={url}
        onChange={(e)=> {setUrl(e.target.value)}}
        margin="normal"
        variant="outlined"
        autoComplete="off"
        required
        fullWidth
      />
    
      <Button
        variant="contained"
        fullWidth
        color="primary"
        style={{ backgroundColor: '#cf559f',  
        backgroundSize: "400px",
        backgroundPosition: "center",
        borderRadius: '0',
        color: 'white',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        border: '3px #cf559f solid',
        letterSpacing: '2px',
        marginTop: "1rem" }}
        onClick={handleScrape}
      >
        Next
      </Button>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

And here is my code snippet from my index.js file form my functions:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
app.use(express.urlencoded({extends: true}));
app.use(express.json());

const corsOpts = {
    origin: '*',
  
    methods: [
      'GET',
      'POST',
    ],
  
    allowedHeaders: [
        'Content-Type', 'Authorization', 'Accept'
    ],
  };
  
app.use(cors(corsOpts))

const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase)
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

app.get('/scrape', cors(), async(req, res) => {
    let { url } = req.query


        try{
            // let services = []
            const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
            const page = await browser.newPage()
            page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36');
        
            await page.goto(url)
        
            const proInfo = await page.evaluate(() => {
                const displayName = document.querySelector('h1').innerText
                const phone = document.querySelector('div[class="purify_dFcdTMoibUeU0IQhEe9mHA=="]').innerText
                const imgUrl = document.querySelector('div[class="purify_W9xnvEHvIASJ3h0FC-rz7Q=="]').children[0].currentSrc
                const address = document.querySelector('div[class="purify_prm7MfDXczhTZvcY5KwOuA== purify_Sardy6hfiet162IZ2pYFPA== purify_m9mNOPjpHD0tNTW6GC+hEw=="]').innerText
        
                return({img: imgUrl, displayName: displayName, phone: phone, address: address})
    
            }
            )
    
    
            const services = await page.$$eval('div[class="purify_TJBmvp84N9Sj6dyMFksHKg=="]', divs => {
    
                return divs.map(x => {
                    return({
                        name: x.children[0].children[0].innerText,
                        details: x.children[0].children[1].innerText,
                        price: x.children[1].children[0].children[0].children[0].children[0].children[0].innerText,
                        duration: x.children[1].children[0].children[0].children[0].children[0].children[1].innerText
                    })
                })
            })
    
    
            res.json({proInfo: proInfo, services: services})
    
        }catch (e) {
            console.log("ERROR =>", e)
        }
})
```

Any and all assistance would be GREATLY appreciated!!!

**UPDATE #1: Made a couple of edits to the CORS options... but still getting the same ERR with a 500 code..**

The img below is what I see on the Network tab

[image: network]

**UPDATE #2: Looking deeper into the err, I noticed the logs on GCP and it states "Function invocation was interrupted. Error: memory limit exceeded."**

See img below.

[image: gcp_err]

**The NEW question is:** Can we increase the memory limit? If so, how?

Comment: Your code is crashing (503) and the CORS headers are not being sent with the response.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks, how would I go about fixing this issue?

Comment: I am not a node.js developer. A common issue with CORS is that the application fails/crashes and returns the HTTP Status Code 5xx. Without special configuration, the CORS headers are not included in the error response. The browser treats this as a CORS issue when it is actually an application programming problem. In summary future out why your program is failing so that a 503 is not returned.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to pass a couple of more options to cors.

Try this in your `index.js` file.

```
const corsOpts = {
  origin: '*',

  methods: [
    'GET',
    'POST',
  ],

  allowedHeaders: [
    'Content-Type',
    'Authorization',
    'Accept',
  ],
};

app.use(cors(corsOpts));
```

Comment: Hmmm, thanks but I'm still getting the same error...

Comment: Try to add something more in allowedHeaders.

`allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization', 'Accept']`

Comment: Done. Still getting the same error with a new status code 500 instead of 503

Comment: I've just realized that you're using Firebase Cloud Function. Google changed the security settings where all new functions no longer have a Cloud Functions Invoker. This means that all newly created functions will have their access forbidden. I am not sure but I'd like to recommend you to try this as a possible solution - https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/issues/395

Comment: Hey Kevin, thanks for being such a help! I followed the docs and it looks like all things are aligned.. but I noticed an err on the GCP functions log. See update Above ⬆️

Comment: You're very welcome! I think you need to increase the memory limit. Check out the google could docs - https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/memory
Also, I'd recommend you to eliminate the global variables as much as possible. It would help consume less memory at least.

Answer (score 0):

Hope to be helpful, I had the same problem as you.

To work around I used an NPM library which did the job for me

https://www.npmjs.com/package/scrape-html-web

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33160917)